# Sharepoint Subscription Edition - Failed to access site at WFE server (IIS error)

Tags: iis, sharepoint

I try to create small MinRole based SharePoint farm, that consists from:

- ApplicationAndSearch (the first server, from which Config Database was created and CA runs);
- WebFrontEndAndDistributedCache (the second one, connected to the farm).

When I create new web application with WFE DNS-A address as host-header (and URL), I see such an error message from IIS:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The farm is unavailable.]
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPSecurityTokenServiceManager.get_Local() +300
    Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPChunkedCookieHandlerV2..ctor() +146
    
 [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
    System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +142
    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +107
    System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1476
    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +186
    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +28
    System.IdentityModel.Configuration.TypeResolveHelper.Resolve(ConfigurationElementInterceptor customTypeElement, Type customType) +555
    
 [ConfigurationErrorsException: ID0012: Failed to create an instance of 'Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPChunkedCookieHandlerV2, Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' from configuration.]
    System.IdentityModel.Configuration.TypeResolveHelper.Resolve(ConfigurationElementInterceptor customTypeElement, Type customType) +1723
    System.IdentityModel.Services.CookieHandlerElement.ApplyCustom(CookieHandler& handler) +159
    System.IdentityModel.Services.CookieHandlerElement.GetConfiguredCookieHandler() +379
    System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.FederationConfiguration.LoadConfiguration(FederationConfigurationElement element) +405
    System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication.CreateFederationConfiguration() +119
    System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication.get_FederationConfiguration() +123
    System.IdentityModel.Services.HttpModuleBase.Init(HttpApplication context) +99
    System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +575
    System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
    System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +259
    System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +311
    
 [HttpException (0x80004005): ID0012: Failed to create an instance of 'Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPChunkedCookieHandlerV2, Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' from configuration.]
    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +518
    System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +729
```

When I change DNS A record to App'n'S server, web application works well.

Permissions for Farm and Pool accounts on both servers seems to be quite similar. I tried to disconnect WFE server from farm and connect again, change MinRole for it, reinstall sharepoint on WFE. So shortly - everything works well at server, on which was created Configuration Database, on the second one - doesn't.

In addition - on every request there is a record in Windows Log:

```
Event code: 3008
Event message: A configuration error has occurred.
Event time: 17.11.2021 17:45:05
Event time (UTC): 17.11.2021 17:45:05
Event ID: 5df1168011984e99ba57729bf5f6b971
Event sequence: 2
Event occurrence: 1
Event detail code: 0


Application information:
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/544621723/ROOT-3-132816338984239912
Trust level: Full
Application Virtual Path: /
Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\ HostHeader \
Machine name: **Internal server's name**


Process information:
Process ID: 1084
Process name: w3wp.exe
Account name: DOMAIN\PoolAccount

Exception information:
Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException
Exception message: ID0012: Failed to create an instance of 'Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPChunkedCookieHandlerV2, Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' from configuration.
at System.IdentityModel.Configuration.TypeResolveHelper.Resolve[T](ConfigurationElementInterceptor customTypeElement, Type customType)
at System.IdentityModel.Services.CookieHandlerElement.ApplyCustom(CookieHandler& handler)
at System.IdentityModel.Services.CookieHandlerElement.GetConfiguredCookieHandler()
at System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.FederationConfiguration.LoadConfiguration(FederationConfigurationElement element)
at System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication.CreateFederationConfiguration()
at System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication.get_FederationConfiguration()
at System.IdentityModel.Services.HttpModuleBase.Init(HttpApplication context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)

at System.IdentityModel.Configuration.TypeResolveHelper.Resolve[T](ConfigurationElementInterceptor customTypeElement, Type customType)
The farm is unavailable.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPSecurityTokenServiceManager.get_Local()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPChunkedCookieHandlerV2..ctor()

Request information:
Request URL: URL of web app
Request path: /
User host address: Requestor's IP
User:
Is authenticated: False
Authentication Type:
Thread account name: DOMAIN\PoolAccount


Thread information:
Thread ID: 92
Thread account name: DOMAIN\PoolAccount
Is impersonating: False
Stack trace: at System.IdentityModel.Configuration.TypeResolveHelper.Resolve[T](ConfigurationElementInterceptor customTypeElement, Type customType)
at System.IdentityModel.Services.CookieHandlerElement.ApplyCustom(CookieHandler& handler)
at System.IdentityModel.Services.CookieHandlerElement.GetConfiguredCookieHandler()
at System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.FederationConfiguration.LoadConfiguration(FederationConfigurationElement element)
at System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication.CreateFederationConfiguration()
at System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication.get_FederationConfiguration()
at System.IdentityModel.Services.HttpModuleBase.Init(HttpApplication context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)


Custom event details:
```

May someone give a piece of good advice - where else to look?

Comment: Failed request tracing is a great place to get more detailed error message.

Comment: Request tracing from fiddler shows only 500 error in response (WFE does not send even 401 responce for autentication) and html with logs in question. There is nothing special in ULS logs, in IIS logs, appropriate message from windows log is in question.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to configure the rights of the application pool account in SharePoint config database. The application pool account should have SPDataAccess role and WSS_CONTENT_APPLICATION_POOLS role. This usually happens when installing SharePoint with another account than the farm account.